# Staged Event Driven Architecture - Weblogic

Tags: weblogic, event-driven-design

When should I go for Staged Event Driven Architecture ? Do you see any issues in implementing SEDA in weblogic by having multiple Queues/MDBs as stages ? Any insights on disadvantages using SEDA ?

Comment: Hi, did you have any news on this question ? I am interested too.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any specific concerns you want to address?  WebLogic JMS is very high-performing so this should not be a problem.

As you have probably learned at this point, message replication between distributed topic members can cause duplicate messages in some cases.  There is a new feature in WebLogic 10.3.4 that you should look at for this called 'Partitioned Distributed Topics'.

Here are some links for reference:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/weblogic/learnmore/weblogic-javaee6-webcasts-358613.html

http://www.youtube.com/OracleWebLogic